# Hole to trace clearance determination

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, layout

I am using M3 screws on a PCB, I need to know the considerations needed to specify the minimum clearance between screw hole and traces.

[image]

Comment: What is the diameter of the head of the screw?

Comment: I searched for Philips M3 screws, found the head diameter to be : min=5.7 mm and max=6mm.

Comment: Well then it seems to me that unless you want to use something like plastic washers between the head of the screw and the board (to prevent the screw head from scraping off the solder-mask and touching the traces) then you need a keepout around the hole of more than 6mm diameter - probably in the 7-8mm range.

Comment: unfortunately the design is compact. does using plastic washers eliminate the need for the clearance?

Comment: Maybe you can use a nylon or acetal screw. Then you might not need hardly any clearance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DIN 7985 **Phillips pan-head** screws have a head diameter of 6.0mm maximum. It will be different if you use a socket-head cap screw or other shape of head, of course.

Standard fit hole size is 3.3mm, so you need to allow for 3.15mm (3mm radius + (3.3-3)/2) off the nominal center of the hole. If you use a larger hole (eg. 3.6mm) you'll need to allow more like 3.3mm.

Add the clearance you need for the voltages etc., probably no less than 0.5mm, so more like 4mm radius.

Also you should keep fragile components away from the mounting hole in case the assembly person slips with the screwdriver.